# Download restricted files from Google Drive REST API using cURL

Tags: curl, google-drive-api

I have written a script which allows me to download a restricted file from Google Drive using the REST API. Now I need to translate this script into cURL which I would like to call from a bash script. I am able to download a file in this manner if the files are not restricted. However, if the file is restricted, I am unable to download the file. I am able to successfully retrieve the access token and I am using this in my cURL command but I am not able to get it to work.

My cURL command looks like this:
curl -H "Authorization=Bearer ya29.a0AfH6SMDIqNCfM6edMUf5EjW2-eQ2S66vA0abwacenoFflAWQ3MNNh9wJQuJGLbuZiu7x5c7jPPV-ETC....." -b cookie.txt -c cookie.txt -L "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[PUT_FILE_ID_HERE]?alt=media&key=[PUT_API_KEY_HERE]" --compressed --output "[PUT_NEW_FILE_NAME_HERE]"

I thought the problem might be that Google Drive is sending a redirect so we included the -L. I also thought that maybe Google Drive was sending us a cookie so we added the -b and -c to the command. This changes did not make a difference.

Is this possible with cURL? I am stumped because I have it working in another script I wrote. I just can't figure out how to convert this to a cURL command that I can include in a bash script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `the files are not restricted` and `the file is restricted`. And also, I cannot understand about `I am not able to get it to work.`. Can I ask you about them? By the way, can we think that your access token works for downloading the file?

Comment: What error does API return? Is it authorization error? Malformed request error? Or something else?

Comment: In Google Drive, you can set a folder or a file sharing link to "Restricted:Only people added can open with this link", which means only the files that have been shared with specific users can access the file. We are able to list the folder using the API using cURL. We are also able to download a file from a folder that is not restricted, meaning it is accessible to anyone with the link using the API and cURL. But if the file is set to restricted we can not down load it.

Comment: When we try to download a file using the Google Drive REST API using cURL on a file that is restricted we are getting this from back from the API.

Comment: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "File not found: 1Aqx6eAitcn7S8HfC2dl18rYrVukNiIOo.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "fileId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "File not found: 1Aqx6eAitcn7S8HfC2dl18rYrVukNiIOo."
 }
}

Comment: We eventually got this to work. We found a bug in our code which was improperly formatting our http header we were sending to Google Drive. This bug was not preventing us from downloading an unrestricted file. Only restricted files, which was misleading us to think our headers were fine and we were looking in other places for the cause.